# Sharepoint Designer só mostra workflow em branco

Tags: sharepoint

Boa tarde,

Precisei abrir o Sharepoint Designer para editar um workflow e me deparei com um grande problema, ele simplesmente não mostra o conteúdo do workflow, fica como se não houvesse nada ao editar. Conferi entrando em outra máquina e consegui visualizar o workflow normamente, já desinstalei e tornei e instalar o Sharepoint Designer 2013 mas não funcionou.

Alguma dica?

Comment: Nesta outra máquina que você conferiu foi com o mesmo usuário? Talvez seja o pacote office seu que não esta atualizado

Answer (score 0):

Problema resolvido. Fiz uma atualização do Sharepoint Designer recomendada pelo suporte da Microsoft e funcionou perfeitamente.